# Injector is missing a mapping to handle injection

Tags: inject, robotlegs

> [Fault] exception, information=Error: Injector is missing a mapping to handle injection into property "data" of object "[object LoadFilePayloadCommand]" with type "game.uitils.loader.controller.commands::LoadFilePayloadCommand". Target dependency: "game.uitils.loader.vo::LoaderVo|"

```
protected function addLoader(url:String, cmp:Function=null, format:String="binary", compress:Boolean = true, illusion:String="N_N_U_S", retry:int=3, endian:String="littleEndian", prog:Function=null):void {
        var loaderVo:LoaderVo = new LoaderVo();
        loaderVo.setData(url, cmp, format, compress, illusion, retry, endian, null, prog);
        var scp:SubCommandPayload = new SubCommandPayload(loaderVo).withName("loaderdata").ofClass(LoaderVo);
        add(LoadFilePayloadCommand).withPayloads(scp);
}


public class LoadFilePayloadCommand extends BaseLoadFileCommand 
{
    [Inject(namespace='loaderdata')]
    public var data:LoaderVo;
    public function LoadFilePayloadCommand() 
    {
        super();

    }

    override public function execute():void 
    {
        loadervo = this.data;
        loadFile();
    }
}
```

I met the error on the top, but i don't know  where is wrong，please tell me if you know it.

Answer (score 0):

Check your AppConfig (IConfig) in the configure method, if you have the proper injection map for the 'LoaderVo' object.